# Creating contract account with ether balance in original sendTransaction?

Tags: web3js, truffle

trying to send a very simple contract creation transaction that includes a value with it so that the created contract already contains an ether balance.  Is this not possible.  Basically I'm sending a transaction like this using the web3 console API,

```
web3.eth.sendTransaction({from:web3.eth.coinbase, data: <some contract data>, value: web3.toWei(1, 'ether')})
```

however I get a revert error.

I know that I can create the contract, and as long as the fallback function is `payable` in the contract I can then deposit ethers, but I'd like to be able to do this in one go when the contract is created.  Is this possible?

In case it makes a difference I'm doing this in a truffle development chain console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When deploying and sending value at the same time, your constructor needs to be "payable", otherwise it cannot receive value.